# Maven Compiler Plugin and older Java JRE class versions

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I'm in the following situation:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;

public class Aaaa implements CallableStatement{
    ...1.5 methods...
}
```

In a very old project with Java 1.5. Now I'm on 1.8 environment so I've put Maven compiler plugin as usual.

Eclipse still asks me to add unimplemented method from `CallableStatement` interface. That's because even if the project is set to 1.5 still the interface came from 1.8 JRE with more methods.

This is `pom.xml` plugin part:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Is there any way to downgrade it and compile the class with no errors?
For example the implementation now asks for `getCharacterStream` which exists from 1.6 version of JRE and not with target 1.5 as implemented.

Comment: Did you check _<Eclipse project>_ → _Right-Click_ → _Properties_ → _Java Compiler_ → _JDK Compliance_?

Comment: I want to put 1.5 jre only on that maven module if possible.

Comment: Which Maven module? You didn't mention "_module_" in your question at all. Does that mean you have an aggregator project with (sub-)modules and you want to change the compiler version for one of these (sub-)modules only?

Comment: yep you're right. but it's just a case. Modifying the Eclipse Runtime means put under that runtime all the worspace under Eclipse...

Comment: Great. We come closer to what you really want. :) What do you mean by "_Eclipse Runtime_" and "_put under that runtime all the worspace under Eclipse..._"? Are you talking about a RCP application with Eclipse's Equinox OSGi framework as its runtime environment?

Comment: Window--Preferences---Java-->Installed JREs 
I think it's quite obvious

Comment: I can comprehend that it's quite obvious for _you_ sitting in front of _your_ computer but I can tell you that it's not so quite obvious when you talk about "_Eclipse Runtime_" when there is one (Equinox) and the one you mean is called _Installed JREs_ (which refers to the build path) and when there's also _Execution Environment_.